# Issue with Jmeter replay for-aws-cognito-login

Tags: aws-lambda, jmeter, performance-testing, amazon-cognito, jmeter-logging

The application I'm handling is using AWS cognito login. Facing issue with the Dynamic SRP_A value and Im getting the below error

{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Incorrect username or password."}

I have read through the post below and included the method in JSR223 pre-processor However I'm not clear on how to call this method in the http sampler. Could someone explain bit elaborate.

Refered post:
[Issue while running the recorded scripts in jmeter for aws cognito login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000832/issue-while-running-the-recorded-scripts-in-jmeter-for-aws-cognito-login)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't call it "in the http sampler".

Forget about HTTP Sampler for that case whatsoever, just follow the advice you've been given in the post you've mentioned:

> With regards to Cognito the easiest way is using AWS Java SDK from
>   JSR223 Test Elements using Groovy language

and implement the needed logic as Groovy code with JSR223 sampler.

Comment: so you mean I have to install AWS SDK(Pre-requisite Maven installation) and then import in the JSR223 sampler and call them

Comment: That is quite correct. "Install" is probably an overstatement here, though: just drop the library jars along with JMeter libs (or point your testplan to separate location with them) & you're good to go.